# How can I get the latitude and longitude properties of my json and then transform them into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet, svelte, polyline

I have a json with several properties which interest me are the latitude and longitude of each object and then create a polyline with leaflet the json is this:

```
   {
        "id": 201,
        "clientid": "cf1",
        "description": "devices 4",
        "latitude": -22.33085,
        "longitude": -68.8210916,
    },
    {
       "id": 202,
       "clientid": "Cf2",
       "description": "devices 5",
       "latitude": -22.3309583,
       "longitude": -68.8212233,
       
    },
    {
        "id": 203,
        "clientid": "Cf3",
        "description": "devices 6",
        "latitude": -22.3343583,
        "longitude": -68.8252116,
     },
    {
        "id": 204,
        "clientid": "Cf4",
        "description": "devices 7",
        "latitude": -22.3358783,
        "longitude": -68.82457,
     },
    {
       "id": 201,
       "clientid": "Cf4",
       "latitude": -22.341195,
       "longitude": -68.8270966,
     }
```

The following code shows how I get the data and how I have the components

```
    const getAllData = () => {
     try {
      getData()
      .then(res => {
      let data = res.body;
      info = data;
      console.log(info);
      return info;
    })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
  }
}


const options = {
  center: [-23.76875, -70.304484],
  zoom: 13,
  };

     <Map data={options}>
      {#each info as item }
        <Maps
        id={item.id}
        clientid={item.clientid}
        latitude={item.latitude}
        longitude={item.longitude}
        description={item.description}
        />
        {/each}
     </Map>
```

Inside my map component I have the following logic and it is where I have to obtain the longitude and latitude array to pass it to the polyline component and paint the lines, which is what I don't quite understand how to do

```
  export let id;
  export let clientid;
  export let latitude;
  export let longitude;
  export let description;



const tileUrl = "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";

  const tileLayerOptions = {
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 22,
    maxNativeZoom: 19,
    
  }
 
  let latLngs = [[latitude,longitude],[latitude,longitude]]

 <TitleLayer url={tileUrl} options={tileLayerOptions}/>
  <Market latLng={[ latitude, longitude]}>
 <PopUp>
  <p>
   Description: {description}
  </p>
  </PopUp>
  </Market>
<Polyline latLngs={[latLngs]}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In leaflet a `LatLngExpression` is equal to `[lat, lng]` so in your case it gives `let latLngs = [latitude, longitude]`

Comment: I understand but they are generic components what I did, the question is how to bring all the longitude and latitude data of the json to be able to paint the line with polyline